# Message Extension in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

How to enable/disable the message extension in bot chat window?

Is there any specific command in the manifest file to do the changes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/create-extensions?tabs=typescript#update-your-app-manifest

Comment: Could you please share more info on what you are looking for in details?

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable your messaging extension in compose box of message you'll need to add/remove the compose value from context section of bots messaging extension commands section in manifest.
You can refer below link to get more details on context of messaging extension.

When you want to enable messaging extension to be invoked from compose box add compose value in context.
"context": ["commandBox", "compose"],

When you don't want to include it, remove the compose value from the context section.

Thanks